# How can I get an MSDN Moles tutorial to build?

Tags: moles, pex-and-moles

I have an unusual question. I need help in understanding an original poster's own answer to his 6-month-old query on the MSDN forums.

The OP was told to ask further questions on StackOverflow, so there's no point in asking the OP to clarify his answer. I would be grateful for some help on this forum. I hope I'm not violating any forum rules or etiquette rules.

I'll just copy and paste the relevant snippets from the posts, in chronological order.

---

[OP]
I'm following the Unit Testing with Microsoft Moles Tutorial (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/molestutorial.pdf) and getting stuck with step #5 in Task 2: Create Code Generated Stubs. 
I cannot resolve SIFileSystem (compilation error as it cannot be found).

---

[OP]
I finally made the program to compile.  But in case anybody else stumbled with this post and have the same problem, here's what I did:
- In StubsTutorialTest project, open mscorlib.moles
- Change the assembly name from "mscorlib" to "StubsTutorial"

- Rename mscorlib.moles to StubsTutorial.moles
- Build (this will add StubsTutorial.Moles in the references)
- Add "using StubsTutorial.Moles" in UnitTest.cs
The not found error in "var fs = new SIFileSystem();" is gone.

---

[MSDN moderator]
Next time you run into problems, Peli and the rest of the Pex and Moles Development team now tend to monitor the forums at Stack:

### https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pex-and-moles

[Back to me]

So here are my questions:

1. > In StubsTutorialTest project, open mscorlib.moles

   mscorlib.moles in never mentioned in the tutorial. Anyway, how can someone open a DLL?

   (There's actually a "mscorlib.moles.dll" in the Moles download.)
2. > Change the assembly name from "mscorlib" to "StubsTutorial"

   In my "StubsTutorial.csproj", there's no mention of "mscorlib". I have the line:

   > StubsTutorial
3. > Rename mscorlib.moles to StubsTutorial.moles

   Does he mean that I should add "mscorlib.Moles" as a reference, then rename it? Is that possible?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what OP did was manually create a .moles file for the Tutorial assembly, by modifying the content and name of the *mscorlib.moles* file.  The problem is that OP did not perform Task 2 Step 1:

1. In Visual Studio, open the test project StubsTutorialTest, open the References node, right-click the StubsTutorial reference node and select Add Moles Assembly.

This is the easy way to create a .moles file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Although I didn't mention it in this post, I use Visual Studio Express, so the " Add Moles Assembly" option (and all the subsequent automated operations) is not possible. I'm trying to do the same things manually.

Comment: I figured that is what you were doing, from your other posts.